# Can't fetch the link of companies from next pages using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to fetch the link of different trucking companies from a website. There are 3501 records in there traversing multiple pages. I would like to grab the link of those records. My current attempt can fetch the links from it;'s landing pabe but I can't find any way to go on to the next page to parse the links from there and so on.

[website link](http://www.truckingcompanies.ca/trucking_new-york/)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.truckingcompanies.ca/trucking_new-york/'

def get_links(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("[id^='trucking_company_record_'] a[id^='company_name_']"):
        print(item.get("href"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(url)
```

How can I fetch the links of different companies traversing next pages using requests?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that? What should your code return? Could you make a simple explaination

Comment: There is nothing more to explain that I already have. However, open that link, scroll down and you will see next page button which leads to the next page. I wanna go there. That's it.

Comment: if you can construct the next page url dynamically, then it is possible through requests. If it is not possible, then you have to try to go with selenium.

Comment: Solution related to selenium is welcome if that works for this particular site @Sureshmani.

Comment: there is a jquery ajax call but that seems to be failing (at least for me in both chrome and FF on two different OS) with problems with at least one of their js files triggering other errors. Is the page working for you?

Comment: Never did work for me and so I thought it was me only who was having that issue @QHarr.

Comment: No. I think it is a problem with at least one of files site uses for Ajax